# Matrix in SQL/VB.net

Tags: vb.net, matrix

i have a Datagrid that stores the number pencils produced each day of the month it looks like this:

```
Pencil | day 1 | day 2 | day 3 | ... |day 31
Red       0        0       13     0     0    
blue      5        1       0      8     0   
yellow    0        9       5      0     0
```

I need to save this data into SQL table but im not sure what's the most efficent way to design the table in SQL.

I was thinking about creating a table in SQL with the fields:

- pencilmodel
- date
- quantity

and then in vb.net making a loop that saves 1 by 1 each cell of the datagrid in to the table, but i dont think this is the best way since i will have like 30 rows and a month has 31 days max so it will be 30*31= 930 times.

Im using VB.net and SQL Server

Comment: So do you actually experience a problem? Be sure to use bulk insertion.

Comment: I suppose you could send the entire datagrid as a TVP and unpivot it in SQL. That table structure is definitely how you should be saving it in SQL, regardless of what solution you end up employing.

Comment: First get rid of the notion that controls do anything more than show data to the user.  *Data* belongs elsewhere: DataTables, Collection, Lists etc.  You will end up with better performing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would create the table that way (as you suggested):

```
  ID   | pencilmodel | ProducedDate   | Quantity
    1       blue        dd-mm-yyyy         7
    2       red         dd-mm-yyyy         4
    3       yellow      dd-mm-yyyy         6
```

also, dont loop and insert each row to database, its not efficient, add it to a dataset first and then update it using [DataAdapter.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx) or bind a dataset to the datagrid view:
[*How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this one is relevant but why dont you create a fields based on the date and time? lets say like this in your PC

12/14/2016

You can create a program that will create a field for you everyday for example when the day passes by then add a column look like this.

```
    __________________________________
    |12/14/2016|12/15/2016|12/15/2016|
```

so what will happen is you dont need to loop in DGV you just do your `INSERT COMMAND`

you just need some modifications and validations in here like

`if Date_Has_Been_Changed then
Create Table Add Columns
End If`